# Link PaymentIntent to a Product

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using the [custom checkout flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder) from stripe to add online payment to my website which uses a server endpoint to create the `PaymentIntent` like so:

```js
app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;
  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 499,
    currency: "usd"
  });
  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
  });
});
```

I was wondering, instead of setting the price and currency directly in the `PaymentIntent`, could that come from a `Product` created on Stripe? I understand that I can just fo it myself and fetch the associated `Product` and `Price` from the API and create my `PaymentIntent` from that but then Stripe will have no way to "track" that this payment was made for this product (useful for analytics).

I know that this is possible to do with `Checkout` where a product can be associated with it. But I couldn't find anything for a custom checkout flow.

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding products to a payment with PaymentIntents API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687006/adding-products-to-a-payment-with-paymentintents-api)

Answer (score 2):

An option, until associating Prices and Products directly with PaymentIntents is supported, would be to leverage metadata on the PaymentIntent to track which Prices contribute to the final amount [1]. Then you would have the opportunity to record that in your DB or query that from the PaymentIntents API.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-metadata

Answer (score 0):

Add this product to Metadata of PaymentIntentCreateParams as following

```
Product order = new Product();
Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
metadata.put("productId", order.getProductId());
metadata.put("description", order.getDescription());

PaymentIntentCreateParams paymentIntentParams =  PaymentIntentCreateParams.builder().putAllMetadata(metadata)
    .setAmount(amountPaymentIntent).setCurrency(currencyPaymentIntent).setCustomer(customer.getId())
    .build();

 PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.create(paymentIntentParams);
```